# SQL statement is ignoring where parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE
university='2' 
AND MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST ('+massive' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR (fname LIKE '%box%' OR lname LIKE '%box%')
```

This query is allowing results to filter through other than those of `university='2'` how would I update this so it strictly only shows results where university = 2

The reason I have combined fulltext search with LIKE is because of the minimum letter count that full text search has and because I am on a shared hosting plan I am unable to modify the settings. As a result I have combined both full text and LIKE in order to accommodate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix your parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE
    university='2' 
    AND (MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST ('+massive' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
         OR fname LIKE '%box%' 
         OR lname LIKE '%box%')
```

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so `university = '2'` was only being combined with `MATCH`, not with the `fname/lname` tests.