# Prepared Statements - Yes I know it's a really discussed topic

Tags: php, security, prepared-statement, sql-injection

**I know this is a really discussed thread, I've asked one question not so long ago AND it's a topic discussed countless times.**

But, I'm still trying to secure a web app using prepared statements.

Truth is, never really got it to work with the answers given, looking at the duplicate question, looking at other questions and doing research.

**It can't be that complex...**

So, I have a `lcl_events.php` file, that starts with:

```
<?php include 'config/config.php'; ?>

<?php include'libraries/database.php'; ?>
```

The `database.php` file, looks like this:

```
<?php
 // Create connection
$mysqli= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

*The page loads fine, so far so good (no problems here).*

**Then**, the file itself has also:

```
<?php

$sql = "select * 
from companies where Company_Name LIKE (?) OR Company_Subcategory LIKE (?) OR Keywords LIKE (?) OR Description LIKE (?) AND Company_Category = (?) AND Featured = `Y` order by Date_Created DESC";

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt) {
    die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$target = $_GET['target'];
$company = $_GET['company'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
$target = '%'.$target.'%'; //this means the data coming from this GET method can have words before and/or after

$bind_result = $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $target, $target, $target, $target, $category);

$execute_result = $stmt->execute();
if(!$execute_result) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}

/* explicit close recommended */
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

The same process is **repeated 6 times** throughout the page.

(tried also to write the query without round brackets around the question mark.

The **result** is the following:

[image]

**No errors** appear in the logs or using:

> error_reporting(E_ALL);
>
> ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Note: I'm using PHPStorm and no errors are also showing up there.

Tired of this problem, it's taking quite a long time for what it is... really appreciate your help, I just want it to work.

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that the query failed, most likely because `Featured = \`Y\``  is in backticks. Is `Y` really a column? If it's a string, you need to use singlequotes `'`. Also, its worth seeing what `$stmt->error` spits back at you. A sidenote: `(?)` is the exact same as `?`, you don't need the parenthesis.

Comment: Btw, why the brackets `(?)` for these? You're treating `LIKE` as a direct function when it's already a core MySQL method. Brackets are mostly used for subqueries. --- `var_dump()` your query and you'll see what's happening (or not). Make sure that all of your operators meet the query requirement. If one fails, the whole lot will.

Comment: thank you both of you,it works

Comment: It's probably failing silently since the ticks are valid in a query as such, given "if" `Y` was a column and that you were trying to match something equaling to the `Featured` column. @tiagoperes

Comment: @tiagoperes I posted a community wiki answer, using Qirel's comment and mine. I don't feel that rep should come of it, nor should I take full credit. You can mark it off as solved if you wish.

Comment: See [AND and OR in WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663976/sql-statement-is-ignoring-where-parameter) and [when to use single quote, double quote, and backtick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the comments as a community wiki answer, since it was solved in comments.

By [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel):

The first thing that strikes me is that the query failed, most likely because

```
Featured = `Y`
```

is in backticks. Is Y really a column? If it's a string, you need to use singlequotes `'`. Also, its worth seeing what $stmt->error spits back at you. A sidenote: (?) is the exact same as ?, you don't need the parenthesis.

By myself:

Btw, why the brackets (?) for these? You're treating LIKE as a direct function when it's already a core MySQL method. Brackets are mostly used for [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html). --- var_dump() your query and you'll see what's happening (or not). Make sure that all of your operators meet the query requirement. If one fails, the whole lot will.

It's probably ***failing silently*** since the ticks are valid in a query as such, given "if" `Y` was a column and that you were trying to match something equaling to the `Featured` column, being a perfectly valid query, just not for this case though.

Comment: Also, when you mix `AND` and `OR` in a `WHERE` clause, you should always parenthesize it to make sure it matches your desired logic. The default precedence almost never does.