# SQL multiple where clause using PHP to filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a simple table that shows the available training courses to the team members using a simple PHP query

```
$Get_Events_Widget_Query = "
                SELECT event_information.id AS info_id,
                event_type.name,
                event_type.prefix,
                event_information.start_date
                FROM event_information
                LEFT OUTER JOIN event_type
                ON event_information.type=event_type.prefix
                WHERE (event_information.live = '1' AND event_information.start_date > NOW()) AND event_type.prefix IN ('GPS','PET','FST','ICT','FSW','SAL')";
```

The above shows how the query working, but this is where I want to add the filter using PHP.

`event_type.prefix` is the category that all the training courses sit within, however each user has the ability to deselect which course type they wish to see through the session by assigning each one to either 0 or 1.

```
$_SESSION['filter_GPS']
$_SESSION['filter_PET']
$_SESSION['filter_FST']
$_SESSION['filter_ICT']
$_SESSION['filter_FSW']
$_SESSION['filter_SAL']
```

This is where my problem comes. I can't seem to work the problem within the PHP code if I want to filter out some of the options.

This is what **I thought would work** until I realised I can't call the same where clause more than once (in this format anyway);

```
if($_SESSION['filter_information_sessions'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'GPS' ";
}
if($_SESSION['filter_pet'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'PET'";
}
if($_SESSION['filter_fs_testing'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'FST'";
}
if($_SESSION['filter_ict_testing'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'ICT'";
}
if($_SESSION['filter_workshops'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'FSW'";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['filter_speaking'] == "1") {
    $Get_Events_Widget_Query .= "AND event_type.prefix = 'SAL'";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated and apologies for the lack of correct terminology

Comment: If you use `AND`, it will only be true if the same field has two different values. How can that possibly be?

Comment: I think you want `OR`, not `AND`. Or use those filter variables to build the list of values in the `IN()` list.

Comment: `isset` will return true if the variable is `1` OR `0` also your session variables are not matching

Comment: You desperately need to put all that into an associative array that acts as a look-up table. This is getting completely out of control.

Comment: @Barmar regarding your first comment...Thats why I said it wasn't right in regards to your second comment if I include OR it counteracts the 'start_date' clause unless I'm structuring it wrong

Comment: When you combine `AND` and `OR` in the same query, you often need to group them with parentheses to make sure you get the logic you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663976/sql-statement-is-ignoring-where-parameter

Comment: @cmorrissey sorry I didn't mean to do that. I've edited

Comment: @tadman thats very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `AND`, not `OR`.

But a better way is to build the `IN()` list dynamically.

```
$event_types = array();
if($_SESSION['filter_information_sessions'] == "1") {
    $event_types[] = "'GPS'";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['filter_pet'])) {
    $event_types[] = "'PET'";
}
...
$events_string = implode(', ', $event_types);
$Get_Events_Widget_Query = "
                SELECT event_information.id AS info_id,
                event_type.name,
                event_type.prefix,
                event_information.start_date
                FROM event_information
                LEFT OUTER JOIN event_type
                    ON event_information.type=event_type.prefix
                WHERE (event_information.live = '1' AND event_information.start_date > NOW()) 
                    AND event_information.type IN ($events_string)";
```

I changed the last condition to test `event_information.type` rather than `event_type.prefix`, because when doing a `LEFT JOIN` you shouldn't test columns from the child table in the `WHERE` clause; if there's no matching row, `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` for those columns and the test will fail.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I didn't realise an array could be used in this manner with SQL. Looks like I need to do some reading. It really means a lot.

Comment: The array isn't being used in SQL. PHP converts the array to a string with `implode()`.

Comment: It's just a convenient way to build up a string containing a dynamic list of things.