# Query to select all elements not having a certain field

Tags: mysql, sql, select

First of all I'm using mysql 5.6

I want to select all the elements that satisfy at least one of these request:

1. Do **not** have a certain field.
2. A certain field has an **empty value** (for empty I mean: `len(trim(value)) == 0`)

I'll make an example to be more clear

```
table2
id|field|value
1 |x    |12
1 |y    |23
1 |z    |34
2 |x    |45
2 |y    |56
2 |z    |  <---- is an empty string with 0/1 spaces
3 |x    |67
```

So what I want is for example if I want all field that do not have field `z` I should obtain (`2,3`)
In case of all fields without `y` I should obtain (`3`)

This is what I tried without much success:

```
SELECT t12.id 
FROM table2 AS t12
WHERE NOT IN ( 
    SELECT t2.id 
    FROM table2 as t2
    WHERE t2.field = 'y' 
        AND t2.value <> '' AND t2.value IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Removed typo! Thank you, the original table structure is much more complex

Comment: `t1.field` should be `t2.field`. Why do you need to join with `table1`? You're not using it for anything.

Comment: Put parentheses around the `OR` part of the query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663976/sql-statement-is-ignoring-where-parameter

Comment: @Barmar I've rewritten the query, now it's much simpler

Comment: Why are you checking `t2.value`? There's nothing in the problem description that mentions that column.

Comment: Typo: `WHERE NOT IN` should be `WHERE t12.id NOT IN`. The query works with that fix.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50a50d/4

Comment: I've edited it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29e55f/1 Seems to be working! Thank you!

Comment: And if you want to get rid of duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, if you answer I'll give you the the best answer for the help :)

Comment: It's just a simple typo, not worth answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from t group by id
having min(len(value)) = 0 or count(case when field = 'x' then 1 end) = 0
```

Combine multiple conditions in the `case` if the criteria must be met by a single row rather than the whole group.