# Can I combine these two Mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a lot of data in it already that is seperated by state, year, and quarter.  So the DB layout is something like this:

| **jurisdiction** | **total_miles** | **quarter** | **year** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AL | 300 | 3 | 2022 |
| AL | 500 | 3 | 2022 |
| AL | 200 | 4 | 2022 |
| AL | 100 | 1 | 2023 |
| AL | 50 | 2 | 2023 |

These two separate queries work by themselves to get the total from the quarters 3 and 4 from 2022 and quarters 1 and 2 from 2023:

```
SELECT sum(total_miles) FROM db_table WHERE quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022' AND jurisdiction = 'AL';
SELECT sum(total_miles) FROM db_table WHERE quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023' AND jurisdiction = 'AL';
```

I tried to combine the two queries by using the query

```
SELECT sum(total_miles) FROM db_table WHERE (quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022') AND (quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023') AND jurisdiction = 'AL'
```

But I get a NULL return value for sum(total_miles).  I tried using variables to try and add up the values and it gives me a different number than the actual total for the state.  Is there a way to correctly write the query so that it sums up the total miles from quarters 3 and 4 of 2022 and quarters 1 and 2 of 2023?

Comment: The middle `AND` should be `OR`. How can the year be 2022 and 2023 at the same time?

Comment: I would like the total miles from Quarters 3 and 4 of 2022 and Quarters 1 and 2 of 2023.  I tried the OR before and it gave an incorrect number sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: I understand that. Which is why you need OR. You want 2022-3/4 OR 2023-1/2

Comment: You also need an extra set of parentheses around the `OR` expression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663976/sql-statement-is-ignoring-where-parameter

Comment: `WHERE ((quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022') OR (quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023')) AND jurisdiction = 'AL'`

Comment: The NULL result is reasonable, as there is no record with Q3/2022 `AND` Q2/2023 at the same time. It can either be the first or second, then an `OR` would be the right choice. You could also try a `year BETWEEN 2022 AND 2023`, but therefore the quarter and year should be combined

Comment: @destructioneer That won't work because the quarter depends on the year.

Comment: Ah thanks.  Weird that I couldn't figure that out lol

Comment: I just used SELECT sum(total_miles) FROM db_table WHERE (quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022' OR quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023') AND jurisdiction = 'AL' and it seems to work

Comment: That happens to work because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. I still recommend the explicit parentheses to make it clear.

Comment: A row can't have year = 2022 and year = 2023 at the same time.  So your query will always return no row.  Same thing a row can't have quarter >= 3 and quarter <= 2 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the combined mileage for both periods, then here's how to do it:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(`total_miles`) AS `miles`
FROM
    `db_table`
WHERE
    (
        (`year` = '2022') AND
        (`quarter` >= 3)
    ) OR
    (
        (`year` = '2023') AND
        (`quarter` <= 2)
    )
;
```

Result:

| miles |
| --- |
| 1150 |

If, instead, you'd like the miles for each period separately, but using a single query, then here's how to do that:

```sql
SELECT
 (
        SELECT
            SUM(`total_miles`)
        FROM `db_table`
        WHERE
            (`quarter` >= 3) AND
            (`year` = '2022')
    ) AS `2022b`,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(`total_miles`)
        FROM `db_table`
        WHERE
            (`quarter` <= 2) AND
            (`year` = '2023')
    ) AS `2023a`;
```

Here's the result:

| 2022b | 2023a |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 150 |

**NOTE:** These queries use tabs and newlines that *may* causes issues for you. If that's the case, try starting your mysql client with the `--disable-auto-rehash` option, like this:

```bash
mysql --disable-auto-rehash
```

Alternatively, you can strip the whitespace from the queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can fix your query by making it

```sql
SELECT sum(total_miles)
FROM db_table
WHERE (quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022') OR (quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023') AND jurisdiction = 'AL'
```

Alternatively, since the column names match, you could use `UNION`

```sql
SELECT
  sum(total_miles) as miles,
  year
FROM
  db_table 
WHERE quarter >= 3 AND year = '2022' AND jurisdiction = 'AL'
UNION
SELECT
  sum(total_miles) as miles, 
  year
FROM
  db_table
WHERE quarter <= 2 AND year = '2023' AND jurisdiction = 'AL';
```

Like Andy's answer, this will give you both numbers in one result (instead of the total), but with the data in rows instead of columns